# float d3 SVG element to top right corner CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I have the following drawing appended to canvas:

```
<svg data="BusinessRoleFigure" 
x="180" y="110" 
width="128" height="66" 
id="WA7WAcWA0WAaWA4WA3WA3WA9" 
style="position: relative;">

<rect x="0" y="0" 
width="100%" height="100%" 
stroke="rgb(178,178,126)" 
stroke-width="1" fill="rgb(255,255,181)" 
style="position: relative;">
</rect>

<rect stroke="black" 
fill="black" 
class="insider" 
style="right: 0px;top: 0px;">
</rect>

</svg>
```

I have the following CSS for class **.insider**

```
.insider{
height:20px;
width:40px;
top:0;
right:0;
fill:green;
position:absolute;
float:right;
x:40px;
}
```

I want the second rect element with class insider to stick to the top right of the main SVG element. I tried **float;right** and **top:0; right:0;** in CSS but that doesn't makes it move. However, if I specify the **X** and **Y** value in the CSS the rect changes it's position.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9kjjpwh/)

How can I make it stick to the top right corner when the parent (SVG) is resized?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your expected result, please use below option
HTML:

```
<svg data="BusinessRoleFigure" 
x="180" y="110" 
width="128" height="66" 
id="WA7WAcWA0WAaWA4WA3WA3WA9" 
style="position: relative;">

<rect x="0" y="0"
width="100%" height="100%" 
stroke="rgb(178,178,126)" 
stroke-width="1" fill="rgb(255,255,181)" ></rect>

<rect stroke="black" width="40"
fill="black" 
class="insider" id="inside"
>
</rect>

</svg>
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var mainWidth = document.getElementById("WA7WAcWA0WAaWA4WA3WA3WA9").getAttribute('width');
  var insideWidth = document.getElementById("inside").getAttribute('width');
  var diff = mainWidth - insideWidth;
  document.getElementById("inside").setAttribute('x', diff);
}, 1);
```

CSS:

```
.insider{
height:20px;
fill:green;
}
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/grvkqb

Comment: Thanks for the code Naga, But shouldn't this be achievable by pure CSS and no Javascript involved? Do the SVG elements do not follow the 'float' property like other DOM elements?

Comment: SVG doesn't support all CSS properities and these are the list of presentation attributes supported by SVG-  https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties

Comment: x:70% in insider CSS works as well - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VjQgak

Comment: x:70% only works if the parent rect is of the same size. In my application's context, the dimensions of the parent element will be dynamic so percentages won't work

Comment: Is there a way that I can nest another SVG element inside the rect that we are fixing to the right so that the new element inside the rect treat's it as it's parent?

Comment: @Arihant if you use persent on inner rectangle , it works for the dynamic width of svg- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VjQgak Hope this works for you :)